# How to loop through an array and put the result to an array using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have an array like so,

```
const array = ["item1/1", "item2/3", "item3/4"]
```

now i want to loop through these array elements one by one and get only the values from the strings i.e., from first array element "item1/1" should get 1 and put it to an output array similarly for array element 2 "item2/3" should get 3 and put it to output array. similarly for array element "item3/4" should get 4 and put it to output array.

so the expected output array should be ["1", "3", "4"]

i have tried below,

```
const find = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (arr.length >= 0) {
            
        const match = arr[0].match(/([\w-]+)\/([^/]+)\/$/);
        if (match) return [match[2]];
    }
}, [arr])
```

but above code does for one array element. how can i loop through array and push the return match in an output array.

i am new to programming. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Why are you using memo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your array by [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, and on every itration split your string by `/` character, then just returining the secion after `/`. like this:

```js
const array = ["item1/1", "item2/3", "item3/4"]
const result = array.map(str => str.split('/').pop())
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It would be safer to use `.pop()` instead of `[1]`, to get the last item regardless of how many there are.